# create neighborhood with Tabu search algorithm in python

Tags: python, tabu-search

I am new to this algorithm and I want to implementing tabu search in python.My problem Is : I have 49 points and each point has properties `wells_ID = [0,1,2,...,48]` .I have a goal function that depends on this set of points just like TSP problem.As Input data I enter the list size.I am looking for the best combination from this list size to maximize my goal function.
I got stuck at this point. after I created initial population like `P0 = [0,1,3,4,5,6]` I would like to create `n` neighborhood around `P0` the structure of neighborhood Is to remove 2 first items of `P0` and replaced with 2 another numbers for example `P1 = [22,9,3,4,5,6]` and `P2  = [9,45,3,4,5,6]`.  note the vector of `P1` and `P2`  should not have duplicate members .
how can I create vector of neighborhood?

Comment: Add more details, input and expected output. Where you at your current solution. The problem is interesting, but as it stands, your question lacks definition

Comment: @DaniMesejo I hope you understand.Do you have a structure to solve this type of problem?